# Unable to upload file to S3 bucket

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2016

I am trying to send a AD backup folder to a AWS s3 bucket on a windows 2016 server machine, via cmd line.

aws s3 cp “D:\WindowsImageBackup” s3://ad-backup/

However I get the below error.

**Invalid length for parameter Key, value: 0, valid range: 1-inf**

The folder I am trying to upload has some large files in so not sure if its too big. I have tested the bucket and smaller files work.

Thanks

Comment: How big is the biggest file you are trying to upload?

Comment: Folder is 4gb in total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `--recursive` option to upload a folder:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive “D:\WindowsImageBackup” s3://ad-backup/
```

Or pack that folder into a single file and upload that file with plain `aws s3 cp`.